# Como preencher um value object automaticamente em php?

Tags: php, mysql, resultset

Preciso de um método que faça o auto preenchimento do meu VO recebendo como parâmetro um result set do banco de dados mysql e a classe PDO do php.

**Exemplo de VO**

```
class Pessoa{
     public $nome;
     public $idade;
}
```

A ideia é incorporar esse método de preenchimento ao meu framework dentro de uma classe util.

Comment: Está usando o PDO, mysqli, mysql_* ?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: Esse `vo` tem algum método que processa algo ou tem apenas propriedades?

Comment: Não ele seria um simples VO. O clássico POJO em java.

Comment: Sem métodos get e set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acrescentando a resposta do perdeu, você pode ainda no `fetchAll` forçar a jogar dentro da sua `VO` da seguinte maneira:

```
$arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Pessoa");
```

[Ref: Manual do PHP - FETCHALL](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php#example-868)

Comment: Mais simples ainda! Obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Com o PDO é possível pegar um objeto standard apenas especificando o [tipo de retorno](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php) da consulta `PDO::FETCH_OBJ:`

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test','usuario','senha');
$sql = "select * from pessoas limit 5";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

A saida é um array contendo objetos da classe standard as propriedades terão o mesmo nome dos campos que estão no banco de dados. Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_pessoa] => 1
            [nomeCompleto] => joão da silva
            [idade] => 20
        )
```

Para acessar:

```
echo $pessoa->NomeCompleto .' - ' . $pessoa->idade;
```

Comment: Bacana! Era bem isso que preciso. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Adicionalmente encontrei um método que faz isso segue abaixo:

```
function set_object_vars($object, array $vars) {
    $has = get_object_vars($object);
    foreach ($has as $name => $oldValue) {
        $object->$name = isset($vars[$name]) ? $vars[$name] : NULL;
    }
}
```

**Utilização:**

```
$a = new A();
$vars = array('one' => 234, 'two' => 2);
set_object_vars($a, $vars);
```